# Prove that $[G : H] \equiv [N_G(H) : H] \bmod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group such that $|G| = p^nm$, where $p$ is a prime number, $\gcd(p,m)=1$ and $n \ge 1$. Let $H \le G$ a subgroup such that $|H| = p^i$ for certain $0 \le i \le n − 1$. Show that $[G : H] \equiv [N_G(H) : H] \bmod p$.

How can I prove such theorem? I thought I have to using the orbit-stabilizer theorem, but I am not sure how to use it

Comment: Both  $[G : H]$ and  $[N(H) : H]$ are divisible by $p$

Comment: @markvs Could you please be more specific? I am follow for $[G:H]$ is divisible by p, but not sure about [N(H) : H]

Comment: Every proper subgroup of a finite $p$-group is a proper subgroup in its normalizer. So $N(H)\cap S>H$ where $S$ is the Sylow $p$-subgroup containing $H$.

Comment: You do not need Sylow Theory here ...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show that $|N_G(H):H|$ equals the number of right cosets of $H$ in $G$ fixed under the right multiplication action by $H$. And use that the number of right cosets is of course $|G:H|$.

Let $\Omega$ be the set of right cosets of $H$. $H$ acts on $\Omega$ by right multiplication. Denoting the set of fixed point by $\Omega_0$, we have

$$\Omega_0=\{Ha: Hah=Ha \text{ for all } h \in H \}$$
$$=\{Ha: aha^{-1} \in H \text{ for all } h \in H \}$$
$$=\{Ha: aHa^{-1} \subseteq H\}$$
$$=\{Ha: H^a=H\}$$
$$=\{Ha: a \in N_G(H)\}.$$
So, $\#\Omega_0=|N_G(H):H|$. Can you finish? Use the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem!

Comment: Not sure how I can do that. Can you add a bit more details?

Comment: I added the start of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. Then $S>H$. Every proper subgroup of a nilpotent group is [properly contained in its normalizer](https://yutsumura.com/the-normalizer-of-a-proper-subgroup-of-a-nilpotent-group-is-strictly-bigger/), so $N_G(H)\ge N_S(H)>H$, hence $|N_G(H):H|\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Since $N_G(H)\le G$, we have $|G:H|$ is divisible by $p$ too. So $|G:H|\equiv |N_G(H):H|\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.